# Laravel treats optional url parameter as obligatory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I am trying to make several url have optional prefix. 
Now I've added just 2 urls to that group: base url '/' and test url. For base url everything works fine. But when I try to reach test url without prefix I get 404. 
Where could be the problem?

Here is a part of my routes/web.php

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{lang?}',
    'where' => ['lang' => '[a-z]{2}'],
    'middleware' => 'localization'
], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::get('/test/me/please', function () {
        return 'Bla Bla Bla';
    });
});
```

And here is the output of `php artisan route:list`:

```
+--------+----------+------------------------+------+---------+------------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                    | Name | Action  | Middleware       |
+--------+----------+------------------------+------+---------+------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user               |      | Closure | api,auth:api     |
|        | GET|HEAD | {lang?}                |      | Closure | web,localization |
|        | GET|HEAD | {lang?}/test/me/please |      | Closure | web,localization |
+--------+----------+------------------------+------+---------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to go about it:

```
function getSubDomain()
    {
        $host = parse_url(url()->current())['host'];
        $exploded = explode('.', $host);

        array_pop($exploded); //remove TLD
        array_pop($exploded); //remove domain
        return $exploded[0] ?? null; //returns null if no subdomain is passed
    }
```

Create a middleware apply it to your route group. In the middleware, call the above function to get prefix/subdomain and append to the request object e.g:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $subdomain = $this->getSubdomain();
        $request->merge(['subdomain' => $subdomain]);

        return $next($request);
    }
```

With this, you can declare your route this way:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'sub.parse' // need to be declared in app/Http/Kernel.php
], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        $subdomain = request('subdomain'); // suddomain already available in request object
    });

    Route::get('/test/me/please', function () {
        return 'Bla Bla Bla';
    });
});
```

So wherever you need the subdomain, you can get it from the request object e.g `$request->subdomain`

Comment: the problem is that I will not get to middleware because laravel does not recognize route without prefix. I get 404 and can't get into any middleware. So, I need to figure out how to solve this without declaring all the routes twice: with and without prefix

Answer (score 0):

Laravel just simply does not like optional prefixes when there are additional path after it as it gets confused when matching (as proven in your code where '/' works but the other path doesn't) so you should avoid it in your case, however there is another way to implement what you want to do, and that is by specifying two routes where one has a required lang parameter while the other doesn't.

Although it will not look pretty as it doubles your routes, This is how I would structure it:

```
// Prepare your routes as a closure
$myRoutes = function(){
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::get('/test/me/please', function () {
        return 'Bla Bla Bla';
    });
};


// Create a group that will use the middleware if it has the prefix
Route::group([
      'prefix' => '{lang}',
      'where' => ['lang' => '[a-z]{2}'],
      'middleware' => 'localization'
  ], $myRoutes
);

// Redefine the routes to handle when there is no lang prefix
$myRoutes();
```

This might not work for you depending on how your other routes are structured

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see here is the middleware.

I tested it locally with `'middleware' => 'web'` and it works fine.
Then I switched to `'middleware' => 'localization'` and it started throwing errors. So I've created a new middleware and tested it again but it didn't work yet. So I registered the middleware in `App\Http\Kernel` under `$routeMiddleware` array, ran `php artisan config:cache`, refreshed the page and it was working again.

So I guess registering the `localization` middleware should fix the problem.

P.S> the route I used was: `.../en/test/me/please`. Another possible problem may be that you've entered something like this: `.../enasdf/test/me/please` (more than 2 characters for the language) or this one: `.../test/me/please/en` (optional parameter at the end). In these cases it throws 404 not found.

Have fun coding!

Petyo